# Code Review for Stroustrup - Principles of Programming - Ch - 4 - Question:3 - Error: Vector subscript out of range

Tags: c++, c++17

Read a sequence of double values into a vector. Think of each value as
the distance between two cities along a given route. Compute and print
the total distance (the sum of all distances). Find and print the smallest
and greatest distance between two neighboring cities. Find and print the
mean distance between two neighboring cities.

The problem that I am having is that I am getting a debugging error stating that my vector subscript is out of range.  I can't seem to see where that is occurring.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::vector;
using std::string;

int main()
{
// Read a sequence of double values into a vector

vector <double> distance;           // declaring the vector named "distance"
double sum = 0;
double smallest;
double greatest;

for (double x; cin >> x;) {                 // read into distance, to terminate putting values in vector use anything that is not of variable type of vector
    distance.push_back(x);                  // put distance into vector
    cout << '\n';
    for (int i = 0; i < distance.size(); i = i + 1) {           // keeping track of elements in vector by displaying them
        cout << distance[i] << '\n';
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < distance.size(); i = i + 1) {                   // adding up all values of vector by iterating through all elements
    sum = sum + distance[i];                
}

cout << "The total sum of all the elements in the vecotr is: " << sum << '\n';  



for (int i = 0; i < distance.size(); i = i + 1) {           // determining the smallest value in the vector
    if (smallest <= distance[i]) {
        smallest = distance[i];
    }

}

cout << "The smallest value in the vector is: " << smallest << '\n';

for (int i = 0; i < distance.size(); i = i + 1) {                                   // determining the greatest value in the vector
    if (greatest >= distance[i]) {
        greatest = distance[i];
    }
}

cout << "The smallest value in the vector is: " << smallest << '\n';

cout << "The mean distance between two neigbouring cities is: " << sum / distance.size() << '\n'; 
}
```

Comment: Use a debugger to step through the code to see where the error occurs. I'm willing to bet it's in the first `for` loop (especially around the area of the nested `for` within that loop).

Comment: Possibly because I tried using the debugger and set my break point at the "for" loop that I set up to keep track of my vector and I got an error thrown at me right away. But the thing is as I was writing the code that whole clock of code worked..

Comment: @dc3rd What was the input that you were passing?

Comment: I am passing `double` to my input

Comment: @dc3rd Please share the input that you are giving at **runtime**.

Comment: `smallest` is uninitialized.  So is `greatest`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Anyways, the logic is also incorrect for `smallest` and `greatest`. And `greatest` is never printed.

Comment: @KunalPuri I am not even getting to the step of being able to put in an input for the runtime environment to kick off.

Comment: When you get an error in the debugger, you should be able to click either the "retry" button which will allow you to see where the error occurred (assuming you're using Visual Studio). You might need to switch to the frame with your code in the bottom right. You can also step through the code one line at a time until you get an error.

Comment: @KunalPuri I was working out the first issue I had which had to do with my post, now I'm working through the debugging and like you said my logic for smallest and greatest isn't correct. I've been working on it, but I can't seem to get it to work. As of now I see two issues: i) I need to initialize smallest and greatest, ii) smallest and greatest don't even associate themselves to the correct element in my vectors. I've updated my code as well.  What suggestions do you have by chance?....I think I may create a new post.

Comment: @dc3rd Please update this question. Or post a new one.

Answer (score 1):

Bjarne wants you to find the appropriate function in the standard library for the particular problem.

E.g.

```
 auto total_distance = std::accumulate(distance.begin(), distance.end(), 0.);
```

"The sum of the elements are..."

Look around https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm most of the function calls you want/need are described there.

Run your program like

```
 myprog < inputdoubles.txt
```

Comment: I don't think this is the technique he wants us to use this early in the book. Up to this point standard libraries have only been discussed in passing and not explicitly explained on how to use them and go through their documentation to find the necessary function calls.